# Sending a file as a parameter to a container in order to be compiled causes problems

Tags: bash, docker, sandbox

I'm facing some problems when sending a file to a docker container in order to be compiled and executed.

In the folder that I'm running the command I have a "compiler" folder and a file.cpp(a basic hello world"). I'm using this command:

> sudo docker run --rm -it -v /compiler/  dockcompiler file.cpp

And this is the output:

> useradd: warning: the home directory already exists.
>   Not copying any file from skel directory into it.
>   chgrp: cannot access '/code': No such file or directory
>   chmod: cannot access '/code': No such file or directory
>   file does not exist

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gcc g++

ADD entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
ADD run-code.sh run-code.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
prog=$1
uid=$2

if [ -z $1 ]; then
  echo "you must provide a file"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z $uid ]; then
  uid=10000
fi

echo "127.0.0.1 $(hostname)" >> /etc/hosts

groupadd code
useradd -u "$uid" -G code -d "/compiler" -m codecube 
chgrp code /code
chmod 0775 /code
cd /compiler
sudo -u codecube /bin/bash /run-code.sh $prog
```

And the run-code.sh file(it works if I run it in terminal):

```
 prog=$1

if [ -z $1 ]; then
  echo "you must provide a file"
  exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
  echo "file does not exist"
  exit 1
fi

extension="${prog##*.}"
case "$extension" in
  "cpp")
    g++ $prog && ./a.out
    ;;
  "c")
    gcc $prog && ./a.out
    ;;
  "go")
    go run $prog
    ;;
  "pl")
    perl $prog
    ;;
  "py")
    python $prog
    ;;
  "rb")
    ruby $prog
    ;;
  *)
    echo "invalid language"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

The problem is `-m codecube` where the it says `codecube` directory already exists. Also, the `/code` directory is not present.

If the user directory is already in place on your docker image (assuming a modified image being used here). Then just skel files copy should do the trick and you can get away without doing `useradd`. A post [here](http://www.dba-db2.com/2013/07/useradd-in-linux-not-copying-any-file-from-skel-directory-into-it.html) offers more info on this.

```
#copy skel files 
cp -r /etc/skel/. /codecube
```

Comment: I've added a `mkdir code` in my  entrypoint.sh but I still get some errors `useradd: warning: the home directory already exists. Not copying any file from skel directory into it. file does not exist`.

Comment: @AndyMarcus Updated the answer. The step for `mkdir code` still needed though.

Comment: I have removed the `useradd` part, here is the modified part: `

Comment: `echo "127.0.0.1 $(hostname)" >> /etc/hosts groupadd code
cp -r /etc/skel/. /compiler
chgrp code /code
chmod 0775 /code
cd /compiler
sudo  /bin/bash /run-code.sh $prog ` , now it seems that it gets tu run-code.sh but I get **file does not exist**

Comment: @AndyMarcus You have `cd /compiler` and the script `run-code.sh` is copied to home, that is why its not able to find it.